# "Cannot implicitly convert (Subtype) to (BaseType)"?

Tags: c#, class

I`m learning to use already created  libraries and to made adjustments for demo project. 
I use some already made  library .dll  where are defined classes:

```
public class PdfProcessor
{
   public int process(Pdf varname)
   {
     status=doSomeConversion(varname);
     status=doFtpUpload(varname);
     return status;
   }
}

public class Pdf
{
  public DateTime systemCreateDate;
  public int  id;
  public string description;

  public void  method1()
  {
    doSomePreperation();
  }
}
```

I want to add some extra variables in  my project, and    derived that class:

```
public class MyPdf : Pdf

{
  public string checksum;
  public double rating;
}
```

When I try:

```
Pdf varname = new MyPdf();
```

I get:

> error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyPdf>' to 'Pdf>'

How can I pass to `PdfProcessor.process()` object from my derived class?
I do not want to change anything  in library's code.

Comment: That error is peculiar.  Is it possible you have multiple types named `Pdf` in your system?  What does VS show when you "Go to definition" for `Pdf` in the declaration `public class MyPdf : Pdf`?  Does it show the library type you were expecting?

Comment: What's with the `>` signs in the error message?

Comment: Could you place your coding with namespace and also can you identify which pdf object its referring?

Comment: ok, there were trouble with namespaces. Thank you for help very much !

Comment: @How come people vote up against a thing that is bound not to occur!! ROFL

Comment: namespaces aside....you are also doing the assignment backwards slightly.  Due to the rules of inheritance, what you could say is ` MyPDF p = new PDF()` which is the reverse of the assignment you attempted.  MyPDF contains fields which are not present in PDF, and therefore no implicit conversion is available.

Comment: @Nevyn - You cannot declare MyPDF p = new PDF() because a PDF object is not a MyPDF object. The PDF class does not implement all the functionality of the MyPDF, e.g. it has no checksum field, and you cannot even compile such code.